# Check if my button on Scrollview is on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

how can I check, if my Button on my Scrollview is on the screen?

Someone who can help?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the ButtonView then, you would see. You can scroll either horizontal or vertical. Now to answer your question, we need more information about your layout or your program. Can you update your question with layout details?

Comment: I have a ScrollView within a linearlayout. In the Layout are 1 ImageView and 3 Buttons. If i'm using a small device with a small screen, i want to set the visibility of the imageview to gone, so that all buttons are shown. At the moment i have to scroll down to the last button. So i just wanna check, if the button is on the screen and if not, then the imageview should be invisible.

Comment: Any view can be made invisible by using:
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: And this can be achieved programmatically, rather than XML code. And its most of the times, recommended to use <RelativeLayout>